# Angularjs appending templates to each other

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how to append code to already existing `<div ng-view>` container.

like I have template with the following code:

```
<p>{{date}}</p>
<div ng-repeat='i in items'>
    <span>{{i.created}}</span>
    <span>{{i.order}}</span>
    <span>{{i.customer}}</span>
</div>
```

then by ajax we loading next date items and so on..so how to make the templates to append in the end, not replace each other and look like:

```
2013-05-03

created
order
customer

created
order
customer

created
order
customer

2013-05-04

created
order
customer

2013-05-05

created
order
customer

created
order
customer
```

and so on..
?

thank you in advance.

Comment: question is not clear please explain more details

Comment: @Ajaybeniwal, on first page load the template is rendered in ng-view container, there is a link 'load more', clicking loads more data via ajax. By default the data is replaced inside ng-view, I need appending, not replacing.

Comment: @Cassius you'll have to supply your js-code. From your comment I'd say you have your directives/ng-view not set up correctly. Because there is no such thing as *By default the data is replaced inside ng-view* except for route changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a parent `ng-repeat` as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="entry in invoices">
    <p>{{entry.date}}</p>
    <div ng-repeat='i in entry.items'>
        <span>{{i.created}}</span>
        <span>{{i.order}}</span>
        <span>{{i.customer}}</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Thus, when your server is loading the next date items, simply add the same to invoices array.